# Javascript Function Issues for Prime Numbers

Tags: javascript, function, button, primes

So what I'm trying to do is use a function that prompts to enter a number and then prints all prime numbers up till that number. I have the code as far as I know but I keep getting an error that the bracket following prime(num) is wrong. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, would appreciate any help.

```
function p5Bela() {
 var num = prompt("Please enter a number: ", "");
 for (i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
  if (prime(i)==true) {
  alert(i);
 }
}
prime(num) {
var flag = true;
var d = 2;
while (flag==true && d <= num/2) {
if (num%d == 0) {
  flag = false;
  }
    d++;
  }
  return flag;
 } 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `function prime(num){`? Also -- your algorithms are extremely inefficient. A proper [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) isn't too hard to implement, and if you do insist on testing each number, your prime testing algorithm does way too much work.

Comment: `prime(num)` is not valid, change it to `function prime(num)`

Comment: you've missed out the `function` keyword before `prime(num)`. As another tip, you can `return false;` instead of `flag = false;`, as soon as you find a factor you know the number isn't prime, but your function will keep looping through all numbers up to `num`. This still isn't an efficient algorithm, but doing this will improve it a lot.

Comment: In the prime() function, you are checking up to `num/2`.  But you only have to check up to `Math.sqrt(num2)`.to see if num is prime.  That is, for 101, you only need to check divisors up to 10.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest Way**

```
function isPrime(num) {
      for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
        if(num % i === 0) return false;
      return num > 1;
    }
```

**With the ES6 syntax:**

```
const isPrime = num => {
  for(let i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return num > 1;
}
```

You can also decrease the complexity of the algorithm from O(n) to O(sqrt(n)) if you run the loop until square root of a number:

```
const isPrime = num => {
    for(let i = 2, s = Math.sqrt(num); i <= s; i++)
        if(num % i === 0) return false; 
    return num > 1;
}
```